# How to prevent next div jump to bottom when browser not enough width?

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <div style="display:inline-block; background-color:#CF0; width:500px;">
        Test div A
    </div>

    <div style="display:inline-block; background-color:red; width:500px;">
        Test div B
    </div>

</div>
```

How to prevent next div jump to bottom of the 1st div when browser not enough width?

Comment: `position:absolute`? But that raises a whole host of other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is using [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/):

```html
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;">
        <div style="background-color:#CF0;">
            Test div A
        </div>
    
        <div>
            Test div B
        </div>
    
    </div>
```

This forces the two `div`s into grid columns that will maintain equal width no matter how narrow the viewport is. Just make sure the content looks normal inside those `div`s when the browser is resized.

Comment: your code make the 2nd div jump to bottom of 1st div even when browser has enough width for them.

Comment: Are you using a modern browser?

Comment: oh i see. I tested on old version of chrome got problem. Tested on new version of mozila then it works perfectly. Thanks. Will find solution for old browser. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) would work on older browsers.

Comment: flexbox is perfect! Tested on both old and new browser. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help :)